# Exercise 1.65 of Megginson's “An Introduction to Banach Space Theory”.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Unfortunately I do not succeed in completing the following exercise:

> Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $T : X \to \ell^{1} (\mathbb{N})$ be a linear operator. For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $(Tx)_n$ denote the $n^{th}$ entry of $Tx$ and let $f_n$ be a linear functional on $X$ given by $x \mapsto (Tx)_n$. Prove that $T$ is bounded if and only if each $f_n$ is bounded.

I have shown that each $f_n$ is bounded whenever $T$ is bounded. However, I have difficulties in showing the converse. My attempt until now is the following:

> > Suppose that each $f_n$ is bounded. Since 
> >     $$\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} |f_n (x)| < \infty$$
> >     for all $x \in X$, it follows that $\| f_n (x) \|_{\infty} < \infty$, and hence $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \|f_n \|_{op} < \infty$ by the principle of uniform boundedness.

However, I am not sure how to proceed from here.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at the operators $T_n(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n f_i(x) e_i$.

Comment: @DavidMitra Vote limit reached for the day so I can't upvote your comment ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose each $f_n$ is bounded, i.e. for each $n$, we have $\|f_n\|=\sup_{\|x\|=1}|f_n(x)|<\infty$. Define $T_n:X\to \ell^1(\mathbb N)$ by $x\mapsto \sum_{i=1}^n f_i(x)e_i$, where $\{e_i\}$ is the canonical basis for $\ell^1(\mathbb N)$. If $\|x\|=1$ then $$\sup_n\|T_n x\|=\sum_{i=1}^\infty|f_i(x)|<\infty,  $$ so by Banach-Steinhaus we have
$$\sup_n\sup_{\|x\|=1}\|T_n x\|=\sup_{\|x\|=1}\sum_{i=1}^\infty |(Tx)_n|=\|T\|<\infty. $$

Comment: Just a small comment: I guess you mean the canonical basis $\{e_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$, don't you? $\ell^1 (\mathbb{N})$ does not have an orthonormal basis.

Comment: @user342207 Indeed, we would need an inner product to speak of orthonormality :)

Comment: One more comment: you wrote that "if $\|x\| = 1$ then $\sup_n \|T_n x \| < \infty$", However, in order to apply the Banach-Steinhaus theorem this inequality should hold for any $x \in X$, shouldn't it?

Comment: @user342207 I don't know why he restricted to $||x||=1$ here, but surely you have no trouble seeing that the same holds for every $x\in\ell^1$?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich No, i don't!